# How ignore error when the data is replaced in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I insert data into the table as follows:

```
REPLACE INTO `test`(`id`,`text`) VALUES (1,'first'), (2, 'second'), (3, 'third')
```

But if one of the sets of data is incorrect, then all the other sets do not fall into the table.

```
REPLACE INTO `test`(`id`,`text`) VALUES (1,'new first'), (2, NULL), (3, 'new third')
```

How to achieve the following:
The first and third set of data is to replace the existing data in the table. And the second is to be ignored, and the data in the table should not change.

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You should not ignore errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 insert ignore INTO `test`(`id`,`text`) VALUES (1,'new first'), (2, NULL), (3, 'new third')
```

**insert ignore command work as replace command but it convert errors into warning**.

Comment: Can we use ignore with replace ?